# Simulating message persistence in SNS using SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, messaging, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We are evaluating SNS for our messaging requirements to integrate multiple applications. we have a single producer that publishes messages to multiple topics on SNS. Each topic has 2-5 subscribers. In event of subscriber failures (down for maintenance) I have a few questions on the recommended strategy of using SQS queues per consumer

1. Is it possible to configure SNS to push to SQS only in event of failure in delivering the message to a subscriber? Dumping all the messages in SQS queue creates a problem for the consumer to analyze all messages in the queue when it restarts.
2. In event of subscriber failure, it can read messages from SQS queue on restart but how would it know that it missed messages from SNS when it was overloaded?

Any suggestions on handling subscriber failures are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to "configure SNS to push to SQS only in event of failure".

Rather than trying to recover a message after a failure, you can configure the **Amazon SNS retry policies**.

From [Setting Amazon SNS Delivery Retry Policies for HTTP/HTTPS Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/DeliveryPolicies.html):

> You can use delivery policies to control not only the total number of retries, but also the time delay between each retry. You can specify up to 100 total retries distributed among four discrete phases. **The maximum lifetime of a message in the system is one hour.** This one hour limit cannot be extended by a delivery policy.

So, you don't need to worry as long as the destination is back online within an hour.

If it is likely to be offline for more than an hour, you will need to find a way to store and "replay" the messages, possibly by inspecting [CloudWatch Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-failed-sns-deliveries/).

Or, here's another idea...

Push initially to SQS. Have an AWS Lambda function triggered by SQS. The Lambda function can do the 'push' that would normally be done by SNS. If it fails, then the standard SQS invisibility process will retry it later, eventually going to a Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation for the first question. Is there a programmatic way to inspect CloudWatch logs given my subscriber endpoints would be HTTPS api's? Also the logs don't seem to have the message content. How do we construct the message again to be replayed? Also do you suggest look at other queues for e.g. Amazon MQ or RabbitMQ to tackle this problem instead of SQS/SNS?

Comment: I do not have enough knowledge of MQ to know whether it would meet your particular needs. If you think it does, then that could certainly be a better option.

Comment: I understand. Any comments on cloudwatch log analysis queries?