# Maximum limit of a SNS delivery policy for HTTP subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, retrypolicy

The SNS documentation specifies that we can configure a delivery policy for a HTTP/S subscription of a SNS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html. Given that the maximum limit of `number of retries` is 100 and `maxDelayTarget` is 3600 is the following configuration the maximum possible limit?

```
{
  "healthyRetryPolicy": {
    "minDelayTarget": 3600,
    "maxDelayTarget": 3600,
    "numRetries": 100,
    "numNoDelayRetries": 0,
    "numMinDelayRetries": 0,
    "numMaxDelayRetries": 0,
    "backoffFunction": "exponential"
  }
}
```

This configures a retry with an interval of 1 hour and adds upto 4 days (100 hours)in total. Does SNS have a retention period of 4 days? [Amazon IPN](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-onetime/ipn-response.html) states

> If you send another response, Amazon SNS performs retries every hour for 14 days.

Is it possible to increase the limit more than 4 days?

The old answers [Simulating message persistence in SNS using SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286942/simulating-message-persistence-in-sns-using-sqs) mention a retention period of one hour. Has this changed?